# How to use Now() to subtract from column of date/time to get hour difference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have searched a bit and can't figure this out.  I've tried using `Now()` in the formula along with putting it in a cell and running the formula against it.

I have a column of date/times.  I would like to take the current date/time and subtract this column to output the number of hours difference.

I have tried a few things including simply `=I1-G1`.  I get function MINUS parameter 2 expect number values. But 'Last Played' is text and cannot be coerced to a number.

It would be ideal to somehow use `Now()` in the formula to eliminate the extra column.  I manually entered the dates in "Last Played" then converted to date/time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Adding some sample data to your question would be useful to illustrate what you're trying to do.

Comment: give us an example of "Last Played": "2016-07-04 11:23:45 (-0400)" is a different level of complexity from "Monday July 4th 2016 @ 11:23:45 AM EDT"

Comment: @justchil: Welcome to Web Applications. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

If your column of date/time are date/time values and it is Column A try `=NOW()-A1`

## Explanation

If something like the `=NOW()-A1` doesn't work for you it's very likely that the values of the column of date/times are being interpreted by Google Sheets as strings instead of dates/times.

Depending on the format, you could use [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en) built-in function or should use a complex formula or custom function to parse each date/time component and return a date value.

The following is a demostration using [NOW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981?hl=es):

Account main language setting: Spanish
Spreadsheet locale setting: Mexico

Formulas

A1: `=today()+5/25+20/24/60`
B1: `=now()-A1`, formatted as duration.

Result

```
 |                    A                     |     B      |
1|   sábado, 8 de octubre de 2016, 05:08:00 |   13:14:361|
```